# Injected dylib on iOS excutable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipa

I'm working on research project to wrap a piece of code wrap into iOS executable.
Its possible because [mocana.com](https://www.mocana.com) is doing so.

For reference please check [this link](http://www1.good.com/secure-mobility-solution/mobile-application-containerization/wrapping-or-coding.html)
Please help, any ideas, suggestions appreciated.